# PyQt5 close dialog window only if condition is met

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am trying to control the closing of a dialog window in PyQt5. I have a buttonBox with 'OK' and 'Cancel' buttons and I don't want the dialog to close automatically when the 'OK' button is closed, but check for a condition first. If the condition is not met I want the dialog to stay open. Here is a simple code example of my issue.

```
# I change the accept function of the button
self.ui.buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.OKaccept)

def OKaccept(self):
    if self.ui.projectName.text() != "": # check if LineEdit is empty
        self.accept() # close the dialog if condition
    else:
        QMessageBox.warning(self, "Warning", "Please enter a project name.")
```

The message box is displayed correctly but the dialog window closes automatically (before closing the message box). The behavior is as expected with a simple pushButton and`self.ui.saveButton.clicked.connect(self.OKaccept)`.

Comment: If you use the `accepted` signal of the Dialog to trigger your `OKaccept` you're too late. The Dialog has already been accepted and it will close. We can't see how you connected the 'OK' button, but you should not make the OK button accept the Dialog. Instead connect the OK button.clicked to your `OKaccept` method. If you need further help, please make a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see all the connections.

Comment: The problem here is that Qt Designer will automatically add signal connections for the button-box. So when the OK button is clicked, it will first call the dialog's `accept()` slot before calling your own slot. A simple solution for this is therefore to go to *View > Signal/Slot Editor* in Qt Designer and remove the `accepted()` signal connection. This will then mean your own slot is the only one called.

Comment: Assuming `self` is a QDialog subclass (and that the button box signals are already connected), another possibility is to override `accept()` and eventually call `super().accept()` *if* the condition is met.